# In a dynamically loaded component in Ember where can I put code that will happen after promises are forfilled, but only once?

Tags: ember.js

I have a sidebar which holds dynamically loaded components. Every dynamically loaded component has a 'widget' object associated with it so that I can pass relevant data to a component. On one particular component I want to display a sorted radio list of price's. This can be achieved in the component.js file with:

```
priceDescSort: ['value'],
pricesDescending: Ember.computed.sort('widget.otherModels.product.prices', 'priceDescSort')
```

The hbs file then has

```
{{#each pricesDescending as |price id|}}
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="prices" value="{{price.id}}" {{action 'priceRadioChange' price on='change'}}>
      {{currency-formatter price.value}} {{price.account.name}}
    </label>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

On first load of the component I then want the first radio button selected, i.e. the lowest price. So I tried

```
Ember.run(function() {
  self.$('input:radio[name=prices]:first').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

In the didInsertElement hook of the component, however the problem I have is that the second radio list ends up being selected. From what I can tell the computed.sort property is still doing it's work when the first radio is selected and then when it's finished sorting this radio becomes the second one.

So I need to wait for my sort to finish before selecting the first radio button, how can I do this in a dynamically loaded component? It needs to happen one time and not everytime the prices array changes.

Comment: Try Ember.run.debounce with something like 200 ms.

Comment: This will work at the prototype level I'm at at the moment, my concern in a production env would be in the event of the api call hitting a bit of lag and coming back after whatever time I give debounce?

Comment: I actually don't think this is a timing issue with the api request and setting the checkbox but rather the template engine rendering and the setting of the checkbox. I think that the the template renders after you're setting the checkbox which overrides the state. You could put some logs inside the run and the #each statement to test this. Use ``{{log 'rendering in template'}}`` and a ``console.log`` in the run statement.